# How to upload an ASP.NET MVC to hosting server....ASP.NET MVC has a.SLN and not ASPX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-deployment, web-hosting

I am trying to upload an ASP.NET MVC4 .sln project to arvixe web server but is not able to see any result. Web is full of information on uploading aspx to the server but not much information on uploading asp.net MVC .
It also has an sql database.

Comment: There is not much difference between ASP.NET and MVC when it comes to deployment. What you can do is, just try the 'Publish' option by right clicking on your MVC project in the IDE. Once it is published, you can simply upload the published folder to the destination server using some FTP tools.

Comment: Please refer to this post http://windows2008hosting.asphostportal.com/post/Cheap-ASPNET-MVC-3-Hosting-ASPHostPortal-How-to-Deploy-an-ASPNET-MVC-3-App-to-Web-Hosting-with-5cbin-Deployment.aspx. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you will publish the MVC project in Visual Studio, it will contain the following folders (more or less)

[image]

In ASP.Net MVC there are views instead of ASPX files (Or even views can be ASPX or CSHTML files), you can see the 'Views' folder above.

Copy these folders and files and upload to server after adding connection settings in Web.Config file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, right-click on the web project and then select **Publish**. If you don't know hot to publish directly to the server (or via ftp), just use a local folder for the output files. Then copy the contents of the folder to your server.